# How to find an Area of Interest in ERDAS and is there a way to make them stand out?

Tags: area, erdas-imagine, point-of-interest

One of the things I've been doing is creating AOIs (Areas of Interest). They were supposed to be at least 30 pixels in size. However, I have lost track of one of them which was classed as "Residential". How would I be able to find it, or would I have to recreate the AOI with another location?

Plus, I'm trying to think of this as if someone else is looking at my work. How would I be able to make the AOIs clear to see?

The software is ERDAS Imagine